# Does Python have a toString() equivalent, and can I convert a class to String?

Tags: python, django-templates

I'm writing a ToDo list app to help myself get started with Python. The app is running on GAE and I'm storing todo items in the Data Store. I want to display everyone's items to them, and them alone. The problem is that the app currently displays all items to all users, so I can see what you write, and you see what I write. I thought casting my todo.author object to a string and seeing if it matches the user's name would be a good start, but I can't figure out how to do that.

This is what I have in my main.py

```
... 
user = users.get_current_user()

if user:
    nickname = user.nickname()
    todos = Todo.all()
    template_values = {'nickname':nickname, 'todos':todos}
...

def post(self):

    todo = Todo()
    todo.author = users.get_current_user()
    todo.item = self.request.get("item")
    todo.completed = False

    todo.put()      
    self.redirect('/')
```

In my index.html I had this originally:

```
<input type="text" name="item" class="form-prop" placeholder="What needs to be done?" required/>
...
 <ul>
{% for todo in todos %}
  <input type="checkbox"> {{todo.item}} <hr />
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but I'd like to display items only to the user who created them. I thought of trying

```
{% for todo in todos %}
    {% ifequal todo.author nickname %}
  <input type="checkbox"> {{todo.item}} <hr />
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

to no avail. The list turns up blank. I assumed it is because todo.author is not a string. Can I read the value out as a string, or can I cast the object to String?

Thanks!

Edit: Here is my Todo class

```
class Todo(db.Model):
    author = db.UserProperty()
    item = db.StringProperty()
    completed = db.BooleanProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Will changing my author to a StringProperty effect anything negatively? Maybe I can forgo casting altogether.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

In python, the [`str()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) is similar to the `toString()` method in other languages. It is called passing the object to convert to a string as a parameter. Internally it calls the `__str__()` method of the parameter object to get its string representation.

In this case, however, you are comparing a `UserProperty` author from the database, which is of type [`users.User`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/userobjects) with the nickname string. You will want to compare the `nickname` property of the author instead with `todo.author.nickname` in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting the following error when trying str(todo.author) in the template: `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '(todo.author)' from 'str(todo.author)'` any ideas?

Comment: Try putting quotes around `'str(todo.author)'` like so. I'm not experienced with Django templates, but it seems its parsing mechanism is getting hung up at the parenthesis after the `str` function name. Or you might rather get the string property of the author, possibly something like `todo.author.nickname`, without the need for the `str()` call.

Comment: I finally got it to work! I used todo.author.nickname in my if statement and checked if that value matched the nickname of the current user. Please edit your answer to include that so I can accept it.

Answer (score 84):

In Python we can use the `__str__()` method.

We can override it in our class like this:

```
class User: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstName = ''
        self.lastName = ''
        ...
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName
```

and when running

```
print(user)
```

it will call the function `__str__(self)`  and print the firstName and lastName

Answer (score 7):

`str()` is the equivalent.

However you should be filtering your query. At the moment your query is `all()` Todo's.

```
todos = Todo.all().filter('author = ', users.get_current_user().nickname())
```

or

```
todos = Todo.all().filter('author = ', users.get_current_user())
```

depending on what you are defining author as in the Todo model. A `StringProperty` or `UserProperty`.

Note `nickname` is a method.  You are passing the method and not the result in template values.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will go ahead and try to implement the filter now. I'm a bit confused about nickname though. I have played around with it before and I was able to manipulate it like any other string and send it through the template value just fine. Am I missing something? Oh and author is a UserProperty. I'll add that to my original question.

Comment: I don't use django templates, so I don't know what they will do. Some templating systems will automatically call callables (nickname())

Comment: Do you mind briefly explaining what the filter would do? I am not sure what the actual function of my todos = Todo.all() is.

Comment: As you can see from the exmaple code, filter is a query argument, specifically author property = some value. You really shoudl spend some time reading the docs, it will save you a lot of time.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/ talks about the datastore and how to get/put and query data.

Answer (score 2):

You should define the `__unicode__` method on your model, and the template will call it automatically when you reference the instance.

Answer (score 2):

In function post():

```
todo.author = users.get_current_user()
```

So, to get str(todo.author), you need str(users.get_current_user()). What is returned by get_current_user() function ?

If it is an object, check does it contain a **str**()" function?

I think the error lies there.

Comment: users.get_current_user() returns a User object which has nickname() to provide a readable name for the user. I was having trouble getting the nickname correctly, but I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using the `__dict__` special attribute, for example:

```
str(user.__dict__)
```

or

```
print(user.__dict__)
```

More information about special attributes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)