# How to fix "AttributeError: 'Seq' object has no attribute 'tostring'" when processing FASTA encoding?

Tags: python, encoding, biopython, h5py, fasta

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from Bio import*
 from Bio import SeqIO
 import time 
 import h5py



 def vectorizeSequence(seq):
# the order of the letters is not arbitrary.
# Flip the matrix up-down and left-right for reverse compliment
  ltrdict = {'a':[1,0,0,0],'c':[0,1,0,0],'g':[0,0,1,0],'t':[0,0,0,1], 'n':[0,0,0,0]}
      return np.array([ltrdict[x] for x in seq])


  starttime = time.time()
  fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open("contigs.fasta"),'fasta')

 #fasta_sequences = str(seq.seq)

 #GC(fasta_sequences)

   with h5py.File('genomeEncoded.h5', 'w') as hf:
      for fasta in fasta_sequences:
    # get the fasta files.
    
    name, sequence = fasta.id, fasta.seq.tostring()  # HERE APPEARS ERROR
    # Write the chromosome name
    new_file.write(name)
    #  encoding scheme
    data = vectorizeSequence(sequence.lower())
    print (name + " is one hot encoded!")
    # write to hdf5 
    hf.create_dataset(name, data=data)
    print (name + " is written to dataset")


  endtime = time.time()       
  print ("Encoding is done in " + str(endtime))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "FASTA_ENCODING4ML.py", line 30, in 
name, sequence = fasta.id, fasta.seq.tostring()
AttributeError: 'Seq' object has no attribute 'tostring'

Comment: It means that you cannot call `tostring` on your `seq` object because that object doesn't have that method.

You'd have to go and find out what the correct way is to turn `seq` into string. Maybe try `str(fasta.seq)` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a toString() equivalent, and can I convert a db.Model element to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768302/does-python-have-a-tostring-equivalent-and-can-i-convert-a-db-model-element-t)

Comment: @JosefZ That's not relevant. This question is about biopython, which used to have a `.tostring()` method, now uses `str()` instead

Answer (score 0):

To convert a Biopython `Seq` object to a string, use `str()`.

For example:

```
str(Seq('ATCGTGC'))
>>>>'ATCGTGC'
```