# use the print () function on an Object to display an attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want print information about my Object when I use print function!

if I do print( my_product ) it displays Product(name = the_name).

My Class:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name = ""):
    self._name = name


    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
```

e.g.:

```
my_product = Product("Computer")
print(my_product)
#Product(name=Computer)
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Does Python have a toString() equivalent, and can I convert a db.Model element to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768302/does-python-have-a-tostring-equivalent-and-can-i-convert-a-db-model-element-t)

Comment: What, exactly, do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `__str__` function for the class like so:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name = ""):
        self._name = name


    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def __str__(self):
        return " Product(name = " + self._name + ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `__str__` method in your object, which is the string representation of your class.