# Is there any way to print a list of objects?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a list of objects, but it prints as `[<__main__.Hi object at 0x7f28482b0f70>, <__main__.Hi object at 0x7f132d0cc790>]`. I want to print it as `["Hello", "Hi"]`. How would I do this?

```
class Hi:
  def __init__(self, greeting, number):
    self.greeting=greeting
    self.number=number

  def hello(self):
    print("Hi I am", self.greeting)


  

x=[Hi("Hello",20), Hi("Hi",30)]
print(x)
```

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is the `__str__()` method? See this link for more https://stackoverflow.com/a/57496151/7613480

Comment: That _is_ how you print a list of objects. You haven't defined how those _objects_ should appear.

Comment: @UdonN00dle printing a list prints the `repr()` of the elements.

Comment: In case wasnt clear, the list itself is not the problem. For example, do `print(Hi("Hello", 20))`